# How to get Meta_key In Wordpress Function?

Tags: wordpress, function, meta-key

I'm using plugin BAW Post Views Count to Count View Post.
It here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/baw-post-views-count/

I want use query post (WP_Query) to get list most view post.
I need use meta_key. But, this is meta_key i found in function of plugin:

```
$meta_key = apply_filters( 'baw_count_views_meta_key', '_count-views_' . $time . $date, $time, $date );
```

So i can't use Query post.

```
                        $feature_big = array(
                        'posts_per_page'    => '4',
                        'meta_key' => apply_filters( 'baw_count_views_meta_key', '_count-views_' . $time . $date, $time, $date );,
                        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                        'order' => 'desc'
                    );
                    $wp_feature_big = new WP_Query( $feature_big );
```

Anyone help me? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query.

```
$args = array(
   'post_type'       => 'post',
   'posts_per_page'  => '4'
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'  => '_count-views_',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```